how to drop or truncate flow file content after handling it?
I am dealing with ETL tasks using NiFi. I observed that flow files were flowing from begin to end. In the fact, after some processor, I handled the data already. so I want to drop or truncate the content to prevent hundreds of Mb data from being non-sense moved further. Is there any method?

You can use 'ModifyBytes' Processor.
You should set "Remove All Content" to true and it will remove all content from the FlowFile.
You can read more about the processor here.


Yes, you can use the ReplaceText processor for this exact purpose.
This is what you put in the configuration of the ReplaceText processors.
Search Value =  (?s)(^.*$) 
Replacement Value = leave it empty 
Evaluation Mode = Entire text
Maximum Buffer size = usually the default of 1Mb is not enough, find the max length of your flow files contents and set the value to be big number. I usually set it to 100MB. 

